# Помогите с кодом шаблона вывода таксономии

Tags: php, wordpress

Вопрос банален, но работая над проектом, по которому возник вопрос, почти без знаний php, я подзаколебался.
Мне нужно вывести таксономию, таксономия называется 'region'. Кастомный же тип поста для этой таксономии называется 'women'. Код шаблона для вывода таксономии (taxonomy-region.php) на данный момент недоделан (нет проверки на таксономию, выводит просто всё подряд из 'women') и выглядит так (вырезал лишнее, всякие div'ы и тп):

```
<?php
```

/**
 * Template Name: Region
 *
 */
 $post_type = 'women';

get_header(); ?>

```
<div id="content-wrap" class="container clr">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="row">

            <?php
                global $post, $paged, $more;
                $more = 0;
                if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
                    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
                } else if ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
                    $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
                } else {
                    $paged = 1;
                }
                // Query posts
                $wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type'        => 'women',
                    'paged'            => $paged,
                    'category__not_in' => wpex_blog_exclude_categories( true ),
                    'orderby' => 'rand',
                ) );
                if ( $wp_query->posts ) : ?>

            <div id="blog-entries" class="clr <?php wpex_blog_wrap_classes(); ?>">

                <?php $wpex_count = 0; ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3">
                    .....
                    .....
                    .....
                </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div></div><!-- #blog-entries -->

                <?php
                // Display post pagination
                wpex_blog_pagination( array(
                    'query'    => $wp_query->query,
                    'grid'     => '#blog-entries',
                    'count'    => $wpex_count,
                    'perPage'  => $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'],
                    'maxPages' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                    'query'    => $wp_query->query,
                    'paged'    => $paged,
                    'columns'  => $columns,
                ) ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query(); ?>

            <?php wpex_hook_content_bottom(); ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->

        <?php wpex_hook_content_after(); ?>
```

Что добавить/убрать в цикл для вывода постов из конкретной таксономии, то есть из 'region'?.. Огромное спасибо за помощь заранее.

Answer (score 0):

Странно что в файле taxonomy-region.php указан "Template Name" - получается, что шаблон таксономии используется в качестве шаблона для страницы? Даже если и так, то в данном случае нужно поправить WP_Query и передать параметр для получения таксономии:

```
<?php

$taxonomy_terms = get_terms( 'region', array(
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'fields' => 'ids'
) );

$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'        => 'women',
    'paged'            => $paged,
    'category__not_in' => wpex_blog_exclude_categories( true ),
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $taxonomy_terms,
        ),
    ),
) );

?>
```

Но если делать все правильно, соблюдая иерархию шаблонов Wordpress, то страница таксономии находится по адресу site.com/region и стандартный шаблон taxonomy-region.php будет примерно такой:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php the_archive_title('<h1>', '</h1>'); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile;
else: echo '<h2>Извините, ничего не найдено...</h2>'; endif; ?>

<?php echo get_the_posts_pagination(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```